# Google sheet group rows template for other files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a monthly budget which I keep in different files for each month. I have a template which is for every new month. For now, everything is perfect the problem is when I do the year budget i need to import all data from each mount which is fine. The problem is when I need to make a change to the template I want that change to go to each file ( i will link them ).

The only problem that i have is with grouping. I can create categories in the template and use it across all files but the problem is with groping can i create grouping as a template. The main goal is to have a single place which I edit and its spread across all files and have grouping.

I don't want to give a way the grouping because my charts are based on main and sub categories.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want to group rows programmatically? When would this happen, when you copy data from another file? Can you please clarify this a bit more?

Comment: I want to create a template with my categories after that each new file will import those categories the problem is I don't find a way to import the grouping. I want to have a single place where to change categories to reflect all files.

Comment: When you say `template`, you mean a spreadsheet which would contain the categories you want to write to the other files? How are you currently "importing" the categories? How are you "linking" the files? Via formula? Can you provide a copy of the "template" and a copy of an output file, free of sensitive information, so your situation is somehow clarified?